# SFTP Editing the file changes the file owner

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp

I have installed VSFTPD.

All the files are owned by the `root user` and `siteadmin group`.

```
chown -R root:siteadmin *
```

SFTP user: `myuser`
This SFTP user is also part of `siteadmin group`.

So,

```
chmod -R 770 *
```

In winSCP, I have edited a file directly(not transferred) using WinSCP, then the current file owner got changed.

```
ls -al
-rwxrwx--- 1 myuser myuser 338572 Apr  2 14:19 common.php
```

I tried to set the umask as `022` and `077`. But no luck. Then I tried `chown g+s *` also didnt work.

Any solution for this?

Comment: But VSFTPD is not an SFTP server, it's an FTP/FTPS server. If you're using SFTP, then you're probably connecting to OpenSSH, not to VSFTPD.

Comment: Yes, I got the answer now. Thanks